Advantages of full BA vs Pose Graph
Generally to reduce computational load, you can forgo full BA and do pose graph optimization with loop closure.
Local odometery is still calculated from sensor input(IMU, Visual etc) but the landmark optimization can be removed during pose graph optimization to dramatically reduce computation time.
I'm curious, what are the positives/negatives of doing this?
3d scene reconstruction will need to be redone after pose-graph optimization but it seems like it's a nice way to dramatically reduce the time it takes to generate a map, since multiple iterations of Pose Graph optimization can be easily done.
